# how to connect with gemfire running on local machine using spring data gemfire with annoatations

Tags: spring, spring-data, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have tried so many demos but I am not able to create region on my local gemfire .

my code is running in embedded  mode but I want  to run  it as client server mode with using annotions how should I do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description is pretty vague.

You should have a look at my [pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples) that compares and contrasts using native GemFire configuration (both [cache.xml](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/reference/topics/chapter_overview_cache_xml.html) and then using [GemFire's Java API](http://data-docs-samples.cfapps.io/docs-gemfire/latest/javadocs/japi/index.html)) vs. Spring configuration (again using both [Spring XML](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples/tree/master/spring-gemfire-clientserver-xml) as well as [Spring Java configuration meta-data](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples/tree/master/spring-gemfire-clientserver)).

For instance, you can see here that I configured and bootstrapped a GemFire Server using *Spring Boot* along with a [Java configuration class](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples/blob/master/spring-gemfire-clientserver/src/main/java/io/pivotal/gemfire/main/SpringGemFireServerApplication.java).  The GemFire cache client is [my test class](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples/blob/master/spring-gemfire-clientserver/src/test/java/io/pivotal/gemfire/cache/client/SpringGemFireClientCacheTest.java#L59-L62) (along with the [client-side Java config](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples/blob/master/spring-gemfire-clientserver/src/test/java/io/pivotal/gemfire/cache/client/SpringGemFireClientCacheTest.java#L92-L157)), but easily could have been another standalone, *Spring Boot* application.

Another, interesting tidbit, is that you can connect to the *Spring Boot*, GemFire Server application using *Gfsh* once the server is up and running.  To connect in gfsh, use...

```
gfsh>connect --jmx-manager=localhost[1199]
```

Hope this helps!

-John

Comment: How do we provide username / password? 
I have gemfire running on Pivotal Cloud

Comment: If you have your Pivotal Cloud Cache (PCC) service instance in Pivotal CloudFoundry (PCF) setup and configured correctly, then you should not need to explicitly set a username & password.  Using the current and supported versions of SBDG 1.5.x and above, SBDG auto-configuration will figure out credentials from the (VCAP) environment for you when the app is pushed (deployed) and bound to the PCC service instance running in PCF.

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but I think you are limited to the "configured" users when you setup the PCC service instance in PCF.  You can configure multiple users with differing permissions & privileges.  When this is the case, then you have an option to set which specific user your _Spring Boot_ app when deployed to PCF, connecting to the PCC service instance, will run as.  See the docs for more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#cloudfoundry ...

Comment: And, specifically: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#cloudfoundry-cloudcache-security-auth-runtime-user-configuration.

Comment: Finally, you can always set the SDG defined properties for authentication, which are `spring.data.gemfire.security.username` and `spring.data.gemfire.security.password` in _Spring Boot_ `application.properties`, but agin, the settings must correspond to a valid, existing (configured) user when the PCC service instance was created.  In fact, this is precisely what SBDG _auto-configuration_ does when it detects the _Spring Boot_ app had been deployed (pushed) to PCF and bound to a PCC service instance. ...

Comment: It simply extracts the auth credentials from the PCF (VCAP) environment for you and sets the necessary SDG security username/password properties.